# How to find the position of elements in a list satisfying criteria

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a list `x={2,4,6,8,10}` and I want to find out the positions of the elements that are greater than 7.

`Select[x, #>7&]` gives the elements themselves, and `Position[x,8]` gives the position of the elements satisfying one of the possible criteria, but what I am looking for would be a mix of the two returning `{4,5}`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using ogerard's processing idea, one can use `Pick` to enhance performance: `x = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}; Pick[Range[Length[x]], Sign[x - 6], 1]`.

Comment: I've noticed a preference for people below to use `PatternTest` rather than `Condition`. Are any performance differences or is it just what people are used to?

Comment: I prefer `Condition` for ease of naming elements to work with them.

Comment: This question is a good example of where some effort on WR's part to give useful simple examples in their documentation would make every's life a lot easier.  This SHOULD be easy to find in the docs, but it's not.

Comment: just a point-free style `{2, 4, 6, 8, 10} // Position[_?(GreaterThan[7])]`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`Position[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, _?(# > 7 &)]` does the job. Apply `Flatten[]` if need be.

---

As noted by Dan in a comment alluding to Brett's answer, using the level-specification argument of `Position[]` might sometimes be needed, if the numbers are not `Real`s, `Rational`s or `Integer`s.

Comment: You can also preprocess the list, like this
`Position[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10} - 6, _?Positive]`

Comment: @ogerard, post it as an answer.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Just in case people get this far and don't scroll down, check @brett champion's answer below first.

Comment: Thank you @Dan, I've already edited it.

Answer (score 25):

As many have pointed out, `Position` can be used for this, but you may want to take care since `Position` will quite happily go into things you might not expect it to.

```
In[17]:= Position[Sin[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}], _?(# > 0.5 &)]

Out[17]= {{1, 1}, {1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {4}, {5, 1}}
```

Note that we got match from the `4` in `Sin[4]` being bigger than 0.5, even though numerically `Sin[4]` around -0.75.  We can use a level specification to limit the depth at which we're inspecting elements:

```
In[18]:= Position[Sin[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}], _?(# > 0.5 &), 1]

Out[18]= {{1}, {4}}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

`Position` can take very generic patterns. Here we ask for the position of values in the list given that they are larger than 7.

```
x={2,4,6,8,10};

In[11]:= Position[x,val_/;val>7]
Out[11]= {{4},{5}}
```

Answer (score 17):

A couple of options come to mind, but I think [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Position.html) can be manipulated into giving you what you want. The key is to use a [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html?q=PatternTest&lang=en), as follows

```
Position[x, _?(#>7&)] // Flatten
```

returns

```
{4, 5}.
```

For another variant, [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html) can be used directly

```
MapIndexed[If[#1 > 7, #2, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]] &, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}]
```

which relies on the properties of an empty [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html) in a `List`. The [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html) is necessary to unsure that you don't get `Null` in the list.

Comment: Nice trick with Unevaluated[Sequence[]] to have the kernel contract the list !

Answer (score 12):

For really big list or a rectangular matrix I would suggest the following approaches:

```
list = RandomInteger[20, 1000000];

f1[list_,num_] := SparseArray[UnitStep[list-(num + 1)]]["NonzeroPositions"];

f2[list_,num_] := Position[UnitStep[list-(num + 1)], 1];
```

speed comparison relative to accepted answer:

```
r1 = f1[list,7];//AbsoluteTiming;
(* {0.0274773, Null} *)

r2 = f2[list,7];//AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.201376, Null}; *)

r3 = Position[list, _?(# > 7 &)]; // AbsoluteTiming (* accepted answer *)
(* {0.73195, Null} *)

r1 === r2 === r3
(* True *)
```

`f1` is ~ 36 times faster than the combination of `Position` and `PatternTest`

Answer (score 10):

Position is certainly the best for the job, but for the sake of completeness, you can do this in a way similar to Select:

`DeleteCases[MapIndexed[If[#1 > 7, #2] &, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}], Null]`

While inefficient when you select only on content, this form allows to mix criteria on the content and position.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, `Position` does the job:

```
lst = {2, 4, 9, 6, 8, 10};
posns=Position[lst, _?(# > 7 &)]
(*
{{3}, {5}, {6}}
*)
```

This is now in the appropriate form for `Extract`:

```
Extract[lst, posns]
(*
{9, 8, 10}
*)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
PositionIndex[UnitStep[x - 7]][1]
```

is another possibility

Comment: you just reminded me that i had forgotten about `PositionIndex` :)  +1 !

Comment: Introduced in version 10.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another, more general (but probably less performant) solution based on `PositionIndex`:

```
Catenate@KeySelect[PositionIndex[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}], # > 7 &]

(* {4, 5} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Version 13.2 introduced `PositionLargest`

```
list = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}

PositionLargest[list, Length @ Select[# > 7 &] @ list]
```

{{5}, {4}}

Compare to:

```
ReverseSort @ Position[list, _?(# > 7 &)]
```

{{5}, {4}}

To see the result in descending order might be desirable or not.