# How to find rows that have maximum value?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, filtering

Suppose if I have following list

```
{
  {10,b,30},
  {100,a,40},
  {1000,b,10},
  {1000,b,70},
  {100,b,20},
  {10,b,70}
}
```

How to find rows that have max value in 3rd column, in this case

```
(*{{1000,b,70},{10,b,70}}*)
```

Comment: How big is your real life list? I think `Pick` would probably be fastest (@J.M solution) if the list is long.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With:

```
dat = {{10, b, 30}, {100, a, 40}, {1000, b, 10}, {1000, b, 70}, {100, b, 20}, {10, b, 70}};
```

Perhaps most directly:

```
Cases[dat, {_, _, Max@dat[[All, 3]]}]
```

More approaches:

- `Last @ SplitBy[SortBy[dat, {#[[3]] &}], #[[3]] &]`
- `Pick[dat, #, Max@#] &@dat[[All, 3]]`
- `Reap[Fold[(If[#2[[3]] >= #, Sow@#2]; #2[[3]]) &, dat]][[2, 1]]`

Of these `Pick` appears to be concise and efficient, so it is my recommendation.

*Edit:* `Position` and `Extract` are three times as efficient as `Pick` on some data.  Using `Transpose` is slightly more efficient on packed rectangular data.

- `dat ~Extract~ Position[#, Max@#] & @ dat[[All, 3]]`
- `dat ~Extract~ Position[#, Max@#] & @ Part[dat\[Transpose], 3]`

Here are some timings performed in version 7:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

SeedRandom[1]
dat = RandomInteger[99999, {500000, 3}];

Cases[dat, {_, _, Max@dat[[All, 3]]}]                          // timeAvg
Last@SplitBy[SortBy[dat, {#[[3]] &}], #[[3]] &]                // timeAvg
Pick[dat, #, Max@#] &@dat[[All, 3]]                            // timeAvg
Reap[Fold[(If[#2[[3]] >= #, Sow@#2]; #2[[3]]) &, dat]][[2, 1]] // timeAvg
dat ~Extract~ Position[#, Max@#] &@dat[[All, 3]]               // timeAvg
dat ~Extract~ Position[#, Max@#] &@Part[dat\[Transpose], 3]    // timeAvg
```

> 0.1278
>
> 0.764
>
> 0.0904
>
> 0.904
>
> 0.02996
>
> 0.02496

(In actuality I restarted the Kernel between each individual timing line as otherwise each run gets slower, unfairly biasing the test toward the earlier lines.)

These can be further optimized by using faster position functions for numeric data.
[Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) recommended compiling (probably faster in versions after 7):

```
pos = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}, {pat, _Real}}, Position[list, pat]];
dat ~Extract~ pos[#, Max@#] & @ Part[dat\[Transpose], 3] // timeAvg
```

> 0.01372

My [favorite method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23623/121) is `SparseArray` properties:

```
spos = SparseArray[Unitize[#], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"] &;
dat[[spos[# - Max@#]]] & @ Part[dat\[Transpose], 3] // timeAvg
```

> 0.002872

This is now about 30X faster than `Pick`, my original recommendation.

Comment: In this case, the `#[[3]] &` is replaceable with `Last[]`, e.g. `Last[SplitBy[SortBy[data, Last], Last]]`.

Comment: @J.M. I was attempting to keep this general.

Comment: @Spartacus: Overkill...

Comment: @Istvan perhaps, but I was typing these (and updating the question) as I thought of them.  I didn't compare performance (or significantly consider performance, really) until after I posted the four methods.  After testing I could have changed my answer to keep only the `Pick` version but by that time someone else posted a method using Pick.  Also, I think it is interesting to show different approaches, even if for a specific problem some of them are contrived or awkward because they may not be on another problem.

Comment: The compiled version of `Position` is even faster (I think it is optimized to check only level 1).  Try sticking `pos = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}, {pat, _Real}}, Position[list, pat]]` into the last two.  I get a speedup of more than a factor of 2 in V9.0.1

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks.  Time for more optimization. :-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please see update.

Comment: That's remarkbly faster!

Comment: This is the earliest ref. to `timeAvg` I've found on Mma.SE.  I thought you might like to compare it with a new function in V10, `Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; AccurateTiming[Range[10^4]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's for pointing out that new function.  I'll probably keep using my own (or rather my version of [Timo's original](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4199042/618728)) out of habit, but it makes a good companion.  `AccurateTiming` uses `AbsoluteTiming` rather than `Timing` so should reveal [differences](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2267/121) when used for paralleled functions.

Answer (score 13):

This works:

```
data = {{10, b, 30}, {100, a, 40}, {1000, b, 10}, {1000, b, 70}, {100, b, 20}, {10, b, 70}};
Pick[data, data[[All, 3]], Max[data[[All, 3]]]]
```

Comment: Or maybe `Pick[#, #[[All, 3]], Max[Last /@ #]] &[data]`, following Wizard's style.

Comment: It appears that I copied this in my edit but I did not.  For what it's worth you are doing the extraction twice which seems inefficient, so I think mine is still better.  EDIT I see you see that now.  I need to refresh the page more often I guess.

Comment: Not that much; but I suppose a `With[]` can be useful...

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Select` to choose only those rows with the maximum value in the third column.

```
list = {{10, b, 30}, {100, a, 40}, {1000, b, 10}, {1000, b, 70}, {100,
    b, 20}, {10, b, 70}};

With[{max = Max@list[[All, 3]]}, Select[list, (#[[3]] == max) &]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a method with a stable sort involving two of my favorite functions, [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html):

```
Module[{a = -Infinity}, 
 Reap[
  Sow[{##}, a = Max[a, #3]; #3] & @@@ dat, _, 
  If[#1 == a, #2, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]] &
 ][[2, 1]]
]
```

The way `Reap` and `Sow` work is that `Sow` attaches to each term a tag, and `Reap` collects those tags according to a `Pattern` (second parameter), and a function can then be applied to the collected terms (third parameter).

In this case, I use the third element of the tuple as the `tag`, while keeping a running total of the `Max` value, `a`. And for the function, it determines which tuple has a `tag` equal to the `Max`, spitting out an [empty `Sequence`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184/52) if it doesn't.

As a curious note, initially I tried attaching the test to the `Pattern` parameter, but it is applied before the list has been fully traversed, so it included tuples that did not have a max third term. Apparently, the function is applied after the list has been traversed, so `a` had attained its maximum value by the point it was used.

Answer (score 8):

As of version 10 you can use `MaximalBy`:

```
data = {{10, b, 30}, {100, a, 40}, {1000, b, 10}, {1000, b, 70}, {100, b, 20}, {10, b, 70}};

MaximalBy[data, Last]
```

> ```
> {{1000, b, 70}, {10, b, 70}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

**Update**:  Here's a nice and short one (if not fast):

```
data = {{10, b, 30}, {100, a, 40}, {1000, b, 10}, {1000, b, 70}, {100,
 b, 20}, {10, b, 70}}

Last@SplitBy[SortBy[data, Last], Last]

(* ==> {{10, b, 70}, {1000, b, 70}} *)
```

---

You got many nice solutions. I'd like to add one more, which is less general, and only works when there's a singe maximum, but illustrates nicely how `Ordering` is useful for minimum/maximum element problems:

Analogously to `SortBy`, [we can define](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25101/12)

```
MaxBy[list_, fun_] := list[[First@Ordering[fun /@ list, -1]]]
```

Then with your data,

```
MaxBy[data, Last]
```

Again, this will give you a *single* result only, not two as in your example.

Comment: @Prashant: I'll only note that, as shown by the result of `SortBy[data, Last]`, the sorting method used is [unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). It may or may not matter for your application, but you need to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
data = {{10, b, 30}, {100, a, 40}, {1000, b, 10}, {1000, b, 
   70}, {100, b, 20}, {10, b, 70}}
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 10 & b & 30 \\
 100 & a & 40 \\
 1000 & b & 10 \\
 1000 & b & 70 \\
 100 & b & 20 \\
 10 & b & 70 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
data[[#]] & /@ First /@ Position[data, Max@data[[All, 3]]]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1000 & b & 70 \\
 10 & b & 70 \\
\end{array}
\right)$