# Selecting a sublist based on Length

Tags: list-manipulation

If you have a simple list of lists as follows:

```
test = {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {5, 4, 3}}
```

How do you ask *Mathematica* to return the sublist of greatest length?

I've been trying to write a `Select` command using pure functions without success.

Answer (score 23):

If you only want one item from the resulting list, you can use the two-argument form of `Ordering` instead of `Sort` to be a bit more efficient:

```
test[[Ordering[test, -1]]]
```

---

```
biglist = 
  Table[RandomInteger[10, RandomInteger[100]], {10^5}];

Timing[biglist[[Ordering[biglist, -1]]]]

(*
==> {0.006476, {{10, 10, 10, 3, 4, 7, 4, 3, 9, 8, 8, 1, 2, 1, 5, 
   10, 10, 10, 9, 4, 6, 6, 9, 1, 2, 10, 8, 3, 0, 9, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 
   7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 4, 8, 4, 7, 9, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 6, 3, 2, 
   6, 4, 9, 9, 9, 7, 1, 10, 4, 2, 10, 8, 0, 8, 1, 0, 9, 10, 7, 4, 5, 
   3, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 1, 8, 10, 0, 1, 3, 5, 10, 4}}}
*)

Timing[Last@Sort@biglist]

(*
==> {0.170369, {10, 10, 10, 3, 4, 7, 4, 3, 9, 8, 8, 1, 2, 1, 5, 
  10, 10, 10, 9, 4, 6, 6, 9, 1, 2, 10, 8, 3, 0, 9, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 
  7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 4, 8, 4, 7, 9, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 6, 3, 2, 
  6, 4, 9, 9, 9, 7, 1, 10, 4, 2, 10, 8, 0, 8, 1, 0, 9, 10, 7, 4, 5, 3,
   6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 1, 8, 10, 0, 1, 3, 5, 10, 4}}
*)
```

Comment: How could I forget about this one? +2 if I could!  (It should be noted that this only returns one list and not ties.)

Comment: This returns only one list of the highest length as R.M.'s and Spartacus' ones do, so these are not the full solutions.

Answer (score 18):

One possibility:

```
test = {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {5, 4, 3}};
lengths = Length /@ test;
max = Max[lengths];
pos = Position[lengths, max];
Extract[test, pos]
```

gives:

```
{{4, 5, 6, 7}}
```

If there are two or more sublists that are of 'greatest length' those will also be returned.

Comment: This is faster than I thought it would be, slightly faster than `Last@SortBy[test, {Length}]` on my test data, and quite a bit faster than the infix thing.

Comment: Your solution is the best, though not in price, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/selecting-a-sublist-based-on-length/1346#1346

Answer (score 15):

`Sort` automatically sorts by length, so it is as simple as

```
Last@Sort@test
```

Comment: Ah, very nice!  It's going to be slower because of all the tiebreaking, but very elegant.

Answer (score 13):

Reasonably fast and quite direct, but returns only one list if there are ties:

```
Last@SortBy[test, {Length}]
```

More whimsical but catching ties (warning: infix ahead):

```
test ~SortBy~ Length ~SplitBy~ Length // Last
```

---

Since Arnoud's method tests the fastest for functions that include ties, here is my terse version of it:

```
longest[L_List] := L ~Extract~ Position[#, Max@#] &[Length /@ L]
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have V10, consider using [MaximalBy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html):

```
MaximalBy[test, Length, 1]
```

Notice that `MaximalBy[test, Length]` returns all of the longest lists. Similarly, there is also `MinimalBy`.

Answer (score 10):

A solution  using `Select` is :

```
max = Max[Length /@ test];
Select[test, Length[#] == max &]
```

This solution and Arnoud's, as well as J.M.'s ones, are better if we have more lists of maximal length.
E.g. for

```
test = {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {5, 4, 3}, {2, 2, 3, 4}};
```

this returns

```
 {{4, 5, 6, 7}, {2, 2, 3, 4}}
```

**Edit**

Since one would like to know performance issues of various methods I've made a comparison of presented approaches (only for methods which return all longest sublists) on a very long list from the best to the slowest. On smaller lists
proportions of timings may slightly change, but in general, the order is preserved.

```
longlist = Table[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, RandomInteger[100]], {10^6}];

{lengths = Length /@ longlist;                                (*Arnoud*)
 max = Max[lengths];
 pos = Position[lengths, max];
 Extract[longlist, pos];} // Timing
(*
==>  {0.422, {Null}}
*)
{max = Max[Length /@ longlist];                               (*Artes*)
Select[longlist, Length[#] == max &];} // Timing
(*
==>  {1.685, {Null}}
*)
Pick[longlist, #, Max[#]] &[Length /@ longlist]; // Timing     (*J.M.*)
(*
==>  {2.012, Null}
*)
longlist~SortBy~Length~SplitBy~Length // Last; // Timing     (*Spartacus*) 
(*
==>  {7.098, Null}
*)
allMaxBy[longlist, Length]; // Timing                        (*Szabolcs*)
(*
==>  {7.144, Null}
*)
```

Comment: Somewhat different results are had with `longlist = RandomInteger[99, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 5000}, 15000];`

Comment: For this list your method as well as Szabolcs' one seem to be 7 times faster than J.M.'s approach, though more than 2 times slower than mine and 7 times than Arnoud's

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively:

```
test = {{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {5, 4, 3}, {8, 9, 10, 11}};

Pick[test, #, Max[#]] &[Length /@ test]
{{4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes use a little function [`MaxBy`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/905), made to be analogous with [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SortBy.html):

```
MaxBy[list_, fun_] := list[[First@Ordering[fun /@ list, -1]]]
```

You need the largest element by length, so you can evaluate

```
MaxBy[data, Length]
```

Note: this is based on the same principle as @Brett's solution, but it is slower. @Brett's and @R.M's exploit the fact that Mathematica sorts by length by default, while my solution explicitly uses `Length`.  I still think it's a useful little function, so I shared it again.

The problem with `MaxBy` is that it only returns a single element, while there may be more than one list of the same length.  Here's a somewhat slow but simple implementation that returns *all* maxima:

```
allMaxBy[data_, fun_] := Last@SplitBy[SortBy[data, fun], fun]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Nearest` has been improved in V10.1.  It with `Length /@ longlist` and `MaximalBy` compete with the pre-V10 solution by Arnoud.  Two ways of using `Nearest` are presented, although there is not much difference between them  If we speed up Arnoud's by compiling `Position`, they are in a virtual dead heat.  For ease of use and elegance of expression, `MaximalBy` seems the winner.

```
longlist = Table[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, RandomInteger[100]], {10^6}];

{lengths = Length /@ longlist;                       (*Arnoud*)
  max = Max[lengths];
  pos = Position[lengths, max];
  Extract[longlist, pos];} // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.424, {Null}}  *)

MaximalBy[longlist, Length, 1]; // RepeatedTiming    (* mrm *)
(*  {0.396, Null}  *)

Part[longlist, 
   Nearest[# -> Automatic, Max[#]] &[Length /@ longlist]]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.388, Null}  *)

Nearest[# -> longlist, Max[#]] &[Length /@ longlist]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.392, Null}  *)
```

Packing the lengths of `longlist` helps a bit here.

```
{lengths = Developer`ToPackedArray[Length /@ longlist];   (*Arnoud*)
  max = Max[lengths];
  pos = Compile[{{lengths, _Integer, 1}, {max, _Integer}}, 
     Position[lengths, max]][lengths, max];
  Extract[longlist, pos];} // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.38, {Null}}  *)

Part[longlist, 
   Nearest[# -> Automatic, Max[#]] &[
    Developer`ToPackedArray[Length /@ longlist]]]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.375, Null}  *)

Nearest[# -> longlist, Max[#]] &[
   Developer`ToPackedArray[Length /@ longlist]]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.376, Null}  *)
```

And packing really helps here (original was `1.26` sec. on my machine):

```
Pick[longlist, #, Max[#]] &[                              (* Guess... *)
   Developer`ToPackedArray[Length /@ longlist]]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.365, Null}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

We could also use `TakeLargestBy`

```
list = {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {5, 4, 3}};
```

Take the largest list by length:

```
TakeLargestBy[Length, 1] @ list
```

{{4, 5, 6, 7}}

Take the two largest lists with additional information:

```
TakeLargestBy[list -> All, Length, 2]
```

gives

```
{<|"Element" -> {4, 5, 6, 7, 7}, "Index" -> 2, "Value" -> 5|>,
 <|"Element" -> {5, 4, 3}, "Index" -> 3, "Value" -> 3|>}
```