# Table - find index of the maximum element

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's suppose that I have table `t = {1.23, 3.4, 10, 34, 1.78, 0.98, 12.56}`.
To take the biggest element I can use `Max[t]` function. But I want to take not only the maximum element, but also the index of the element (so, which element in table it is).
Is any function which helps to take the indes of element, when I know the value of this element?

Comment: `Position[t,Max[t]]`

Comment: Related: [how-do-i-find-the-elements-in-a-list-that-return-the-highest-value-for-a-functio](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/how-do-i-find-the-elements-in-a-list-that-return-the-highest-value-for-a-functio)

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate, for now.  There are a number of similar questions on this site that can be found by searching for Position, Ordering, etc.  Several deal specifically with maximum values.  Also, your question is not fully specified; do you want only the position of *one* or *all* maximum values for example?  Further, this question is arguably "easily found in the documentation" for `Position`.  If you have a more specific question please edit accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can you explain how I have to look in documentation for method 'Position' or 'Ordering', when I don't know that this method exist?

Comment: @Ziva my closing this question was not meant to chastise you for asking; rather it is to keep the site organized to the extend that I am able.  I know that the documentation can be hard to navigate.  Searching this site is hopefully a bit easier, and every duplicate question provides another avenue to find what one is looking for, e.g. this one now uses the terminology "index" and in addition to Sjoerd's answer it points to two more questions which are hopefully helpful.  (continued)

Comment: For the documentation itself you could conceivably have found `Position` by searching for "index" the second result of which is the page for `StringPosition`, and the first link under "See Also" on that page is to `Position`.  Convoluted, I know, but that's fairly common, so if you want to learn to use the documentation I suggest getting used to it.  Another search term that would have been more direct is "Find" the second result for which is `Position`.

Comment: Here is another related question: [(900)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900/121).  Also, if you choose to use `Ordering` please read: [(2729)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2729/121)

Answer (score 53):

```
Ordering[t, -1]
```

which is orders of magnitude faster than

```
Position[t,Max[t]]
```

Comment: Since the op states after initial example " Is any function which helps to take the indes of element, when I know the value of this element?", a much more general statement, not sure ordering will address it. Of course, if one is only after the last instance of a maximum (because if there are multiple, ordering again becomes a bit useless), this is the fastest way.

Comment: Make sure to actually get the max index out of the list that "Ordering" returns.  `Ordering[t,-1][[1]]`

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.