# Finding the position in a list where the maximum or minimum value occurs

Tags: list-manipulation

We can use `Max[exampleList]` or `Min[exampleList]` to find the maxima and minima of `exampleList`, however, is there a similar standalone function that returns something like `{position in array, maximum value in the array}` or `{position in array, minimum value in the array}`, i.e. both the position and value of the maximum or minimum element in `exampleList`?  It seems awkward to have to write `Position[exampleList,Max[exampleList]]` or `Position[exampleList,Min[exampleList]]`?

Comment: Take a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html for the position.

Comment: @blochwave Yes, thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Related: [(900)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900/121), [(1342)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1342/121),
[(2177)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2177/121)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Position[list,_?(#==Max[list]&)]
```

or shorter (per your comment...)

```
Position[list,Max[list]]
```

will do the trick, obviously change `Max` to `Min` for minimum...

Or, as suggested in comments

```
Ordering[list,1]
Ordering[list,-1]
```

Will give positions of minimum and maximum, respectively.

**Computation times**

```
order[n_] := Block[{},
  list = RandomReal[1, n];
  t1 = (Position[list, Min@list]; // RepeatedTiming // First);
  t2 = (Ordering[list, 1]; // RepeatedTiming // First);
  {{n, t1}, {n, t2}}]
tab = ParallelTable[order[Floor[1.1^n]], {n, 1, 100, 1}];
ListLogLogPlot[{tab[[All, 1]], tab[[All, 2]]}]
```

[image]

`Ordering` is much faster.

Comment: Why can't we just write `Position[exampleList,Max[exampleList]]`?  Sorry, I wrote that just as you were posting this answer.

Comment: @Geof: Well, for one thing, that's incomplete. The first argument to `Position` is the target list, and `Max` does not return a list...

Comment: OK, I like the use of Ordering here, that's what I was after!

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I fixed the comment.  I meant, why can't "(#==Max[list]&)" just be "Max[exampleList]"?

Comment: @geof: you can, I'm just in the habit of having complex functions there...

Comment: I added a comparison of computation times, hope you don't mind.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work correctly when precision numbers are involved, see my question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/265106/45020. Any thoughts?