# Finding position of the maximum value of each subset

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following set:

```
list = {{32/39, 1/5, 0, 0, 0}, {5/33, 3/5, 1/3, 0, 3/4}};
```

I need to find the position of maximum value from each subset.
I tried

```
Position[list, Max[list]]
```

and it gives the position `{{1,1}}`. But my result should be `{{1,1}, {2,5}}`/

Comment: From the documentation for  [Ordering](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) (=> Props and Relations), to find the position of the maximum element: `Ordering[#1, -1] & /@ list` -> {{1}, {5}}. See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45646/106)

Answer (score 11):

```
Position[Unitize[# - Max @ #]& /@ list, 0]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 5}}

Also:

```
MapIndexed[Join[#2, Ordering[#, -1]]&, list]
Join @@@ MapIndexed[Prepend, Position[#, Max @ #] & /@ list]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 5}}

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!

Answer (score 11):

Here is an answer that makes extensive use of internal functions, but is significantly faster.

```
maxPositions[list_?MatrixQ] := With[
    {
    mask = UnitStep @ Subtract[
        list,
        Random`Private`MapThreadMax[Transpose@list]
    ]
    },
    Mod[Random`Private`PositionsOf[Flatten @ mask, 1], Dimensions[list][[2]], 1]
]
```

The function does not return the indices, only the maxima. Comparison:

```
data = RandomReal[10, {10^5, 5}];

r1 = maxPositions[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Position[Unitize[#-Max@#]&/@data,0]; //RepeatedTiming (* kglr *)

Thread[{Range[10^5], r1}] === r2
```

> {0.00737, Null}
>
> {0.088, Null}
>
> True

The other answers are much slower.

**Update**

It seems that `` Random`Private`MapThreadMax `` was introduced between 10.3.1 and 11.1. For versions of Mathematica that don't have that function you can use:

```
maxPositions[list_?MatrixQ] := With[
    {mask = UnitStep[list + Random`Private`MapThreadMin[-Transpose@list]},
    Mod[Random`Private`PositionsOf[Flatten @ mask, 1], Dimensions[list][[2]], 1]
]
```

Comment: thanks for introducing me to these internal functions. +1 of course :)

Comment: @Carl Woll I tried to use your answer but those `Private` functions do not get identified, Using windows10, math v11.0

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Wow, `Random`Private`PositionsOf` will be super-helpful. Thanks for introducing me to it!

Comment: I'm surprised to see ``Random`Private`PositionsOf[Range[1., 3.], 2.]`` comes back unevaluated.

Answer (score 9):

```
MapIndexed[
 Join[#2, Position[#, Max[#]][[1]]] &
, list
]
```

Comment: Appreciate it!!

Comment: @Kuba Is this solution robust for a list of floats?

Comment: @AlGuy I am not sure but I would say probably because the number matched by position was earlier picked by `Max` from that sublist, it exactly that number should be found.

Answer (score 6):

```
MapThread[Flatten@{#1, Position[#2, #3]} &,
 {Range@Length@list, list, Max /@ list}]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {{32/39, 1/5, 0, 0, 0}, {5/33, 3/5, 1/3, 0, 3/4}};
```

From the documentation for [`Max`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html): "Max[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2],…}, {Subscript[y, 1],…},…] yields the largest element of any of the lists." Consequently,

```
Max[list]

(* 32/39 *)
```

From the documentation for [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html): "Position returns a list of positions in a form suitable for use in Extract, ReplacePart, and MapAt. The form is different from the one used in Part."

```
pos = Position[list, Max[list]]

(* {{1, 1}} *)

Extract[list, pos]

(* {32/39} *)
```

If you want the `Max` of each of the sublists of `list`

```
Max /@ list

(* {32/39, 3/4} *)

pos2 = Position[#, Max[#]] & /@ list

(* {{{1}}, {{5}}} *)

Extract[list[[#]], pos2[[#]]] & /@ {1, 2}

(* {{32/39}, {3/4}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
fun = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Position[x, Max[x]][[1, 1]] , 
Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",  CompilationTarget -> "C"]; 

{Range@Length@Flatten[list, {1}], fun[list]} // Transpose
```

Compile seems very fast :slightly slower than Carl's r1 on matrix with fewer than 10^4 points, faster on matrix with over 10^5 points)

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

This also works but slow for large list.

```
Join @@ (Position[list, #] & /@ Max /@ list)
```

**Edit:** Above code only works if elements are not repeated.

This one works for all cases and pretty fast.

```
Transpose@{Range@Length@list, Flatten[Position[#, Max[#]] & /@ list]}
```

Comment: Try `list = {{6, 5}, {5, 1}}`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 4):

Since Version 13.2 there is `PositionLargest`:

```
list = {{32/39, 1/5, 0, 0, 0}, {5/33, 3/5, 1/3, 0, 3/4}};

ps = PositionLargest /@ list
```

{{1}, {5}}

```
mi = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1[[1]]} &] @ ps
```

{{1, 1}, {2, 5}}

```
Extract[mi] @ list
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `PositionLargest` (+1). I simply cannot remember this one. However, for `X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000000}];`, a call to `Ordering[X, -1]` takes just `0.0455106` seconds on my machine while `PositionLargest[X]` requires `0.385012` seconds. More than 8 times as long! (And more than 60 times as long as a similar C++ function would take...) =/

Comment: Thanks, Henrik, I wasn't aware that `PositionLargest ` is such a poor performer. Many of the newer functions (all of the Sequence-functions, `DeleteElements` etc.)  are pretty slow. I hope, that WR will accelerate them in future releases.

Answer (score 4):

Another method using `MaximalBy`:

```
Position[list, #][[1]] & @@@ (list // Map[x |-> MaximalBy[x, Position]])

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 5}}*)
```

Or using `SortBy`:

```
Position[list, #][[1]] & /@ Last /@ (SortBy[#, Position] & /@ list)

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 5}}*)
```

Or using `GroupBy`:

```
Values@((x |-> Position[list, x][[1]]) /@ AssociationMap[Reverse, GroupBy[list, x |-> Max[x]]])

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 5}}*)
```

Another possibility is to use `GroupBy`, `Position` and `KeyMap` as follows:

```
Keys@KeyMap[Position[list, #][[1]] &, GroupBy[list, Max]]

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 5}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

We could also use `TakeLargest`

```
list = {{32/39, 1/5, 0, 0, 0}, {5/33, 3/5, 1/3, 0, 3/4}};

max = Splice @ TakeLargest[# -> All, 1] & /@ list
```

[image]

```
Dataset @ max
```

[image]

```
Values @ max
```

{{32/39, 1}, {3/4, 5}}

To only get the positions:

```
Lookup[max, "Index"]
```

{1, 5}

```
Splice @ TakeLargest[# -> "Index", 1] & /@ list
```

{1, 5}

Positions of the two largest elements:

```
TakeLargest[# -> "Index", 2] & /@ list
```

{{1, 2}, {5, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

Reinventing the bicycle here, but could be useful to someone.

```
list = {{32/39, 1/5, 0, 0, 0}, {5/33, 3/5, 1/3, 0, 3/4}};

Table[Flatten[{i, Position[aux = list[[i]], Max[aux]]}], {i, 1, 
Length[list]}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 5}}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Threshold`:**

```
list = {{32/39, 1/5, 0, 0, 0}, {5/33, 3/5, 1/3, 0, 3/4}};

pos = list // Map[Threshold[#, {"LargestValues", 1}] &] // 
   Position[#, Except[0], {2}, Heads -> False] & // 
  GatherBy[#, First] &
```

> {{{1, 1}}, {{2, 5}}}

```
Extract[list, #] & /@ pos
```

> {{32/39}, {3/4}}