# Finding the position of maximal value when dealing with precision numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, arbitrary-precision

In for example [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45646/45020) a solution is given to find the position of a maximal value. However, this solutions seems to run into trouble when dealing with precision numbers. Take the following example:

```
example = SetPrecision[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]
   , 200];
Position[example, MaximalBy[example, #[[2]] &]]
```

The expectation is that this will produce some position. Instead it givesd `{}` because no match is found. One can check by hand if the "maximal" entry is say the first one (once can repalce the first `10` in the above code with `1` so that this is always true) that

```
MatchQ[example[[1]],MaximalBy[example, #[[2]] &]]
```

indeed returns false despite these entries looking the same and originating from the same source. The issue seems to be in the precision numbers involved.

How do I get a robust version of a function`positionMaximalBy` that returns the position of the element that `MaximalBy` outputs?

Comment: I don't think the precision of the arguments has anything to do with this. Instead, `MaximalBy` returns *a list* of results; that pattern is not found in your input, so `Position` correctly returns an empty list. The following will work: `Position[example, First@ MaximalBy[...]]` if you just want the first occurrence, or `Position[example, Alternatives@@ MaximalBy[...]]` if you want them all.

Comment: Oops that was stupid.

Comment: As an alternative to using `SetPrecision`, `RandomReal` can take the option `WorkingPrecision`, e.g., `example = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 200]`