# Find the longest constant sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list

```
list = {1,2,2,2,2,5,1,3,2,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,10,-3};
```

how to find the longest constant sublist (or equivalently the element and the number of times it is repeated)?

(in this example, {6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6} or {6,11})

Comment: It looks like this question is *almost* a duplicate of [Selecting a sublist based on Length](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1342/121), which shamefully the system had to point out to me. :-o

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Concisely and reasonably efficiently:

```
Last @ Sort @ Split @ list
```

> ```
> {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
> ```

More efficiently:

```
# ~Extract~ Ordering[#, -1] & @ Split @ list
```

> ```
> {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
> ```

Multiple longest runs:

```
longestRuns[x_List] :=
  With[{sp = Split[x]},
    sp ~Extract~ Position[#, Max@#] &[Length /@ sp] & @ x
  ]

{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6} // longestRuns
```

> ```
> {{2, 2}, {4, 4}}
> ```

Less efficiently but having fun with patterns:

```
list /. {___, seq : Longest[x_ ..], ___} :> {seq}
```

> ```
> {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
> ```

Answer (score 10):

I post this somewhat ridiculous answer for 'fun', acknowledging all the given answers directly answer the question, esp Mr. Wizard. I post just ways of 'visualizing' longest run:

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
   10, -3};
With[{w = Union@list},
 ArrayPlot[Map[Function[x, Unitize[# - x] & /@ list], w], 
  FrameTicks -> {{Thread[{Range[Length@w], w}], 
     None}, {Range[Length@list], None}}]]
```

[image]

Of course you could `ArrayPlot` with your own color scheme.

Increasing the overkill:

```
ind = Range[Length@list];
gg = With[{pt = Partition[ind, 2, 1]}, 
   UndirectedEdge @@@ Pick[pt, Length@Union[list[[#]]] == 1 & /@ pt]];
gp = Graph[ind, gg, 
  VertexLabels -> 
   Thread[ind -> (Placed[
         Framed[#, Background -> Yellow, RoundingRadius -> 4], 
         Center] & /@ list)], 
  GraphLayout -> "HighDimensionalEmbedding", VertexSize -> 0, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {1, 2}, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

[image]

Note:

```
comp = ConnectedComponents[gp] /. Thread[ind -> list]
```

yields:

```
{{6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}, {2, 2, 2, 
  2}, {5}, {3}, {1}, {10}, {1}, {2}, {-3}}
```

or increasing the overkill using `CommunityGraphPlot`:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[
 Graph[ind, gg, 
  VertexLabels -> 
   Thread[ind -> (Placed[
         Style[#, White, Bold, FontFamily -> "Kartika", 12], 
         Center] & /@ list)], VertexSize -> 1.5, 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]], ConnectedComponents[gp], 
 Method -> "Hierarchical", CommunityRegionStyle -> Green]
```

[image]

or showing the 'chain':

```
CommunityGraphPlot[
 Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[ind, 2, 1], 
  VertexLabels -> 
   Thread[ind -> (Placed[
         Style[#, White, Bold, FontFamily -> "Kartika", 10], 
         Center] & /@ list)], VertexSize -> 1, EdgeStyle -> Thick], 
 ConnectedComponents[gp], CommunityRegionStyle -> Green, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In Version 10 you can use the new function [MaximalBy](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html):

```
Split@list~MaximalBy~Length
```

> {{6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}}

You can also use it in the operator form:

```
MaximalBy[Length]@Split@list
```

Comment: Wow, finally there is MaximalBy. Great! From time to time I need to do it myself before version 10 :)

Answer (score 5):

Faster, properly returns multiple sublists if there are more than one sequence with maximal length:

```
Module[{l = #, 
        sa = Append[SparseArray[Differences@#]["AdjacencyLists"], Length@#],
        sap, p},

   sap = Prepend[Most@sa + 1, 1];
   p = Pick[Transpose[{sap, sa}], sa - sap, Max[sa - sap]];
   l[[Span @@ #]] & /@ p] &[targetListHere]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, maybe not so efficient:

```
With[{list = {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}}, 
LongestCommonSubsequence[list, 
ConstantArray[#, Length@list]] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates@list)]
```