# Locate Start and End Positions of Repeated Sequences in a list

Tags: pattern-matching, sequence

```
ListA = {14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 12, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 12, 14, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 54, 48, 48, 48, 52, 46, 
46, 46, 46, 52, 52, 54, 62, 56, 52, 54, 50, 46, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 
54, 38, 40, 46, 52, 44, 52, 50, 56, 54, 54, 56, 46, 46, 56, 48, 58, 
60, 54, 54, 46, 54, 50, 52, 54, 48, 56, 48, 56, 48, 52, 44, 54, 56, 
44, 54, 44, 54, 50, 50, 38, 40, 44, 44, 52, 42, 42, 42, 48, 44, 44, 
44, 42, 38, 42, 42, 44, 38, 36, 36, 40, 40, 42, 40, 38, 38, 40, 40, 
42, 40, 40, 42, 44, 68, 46, 38, 40, 62, 54, 40, 40, 40, 40, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 44}
```

I need to locate the start and end positions of any sequence of repeated successive numbers. So if a repeat goes on for 10 successive numbers I need the first and tenth position, and similar for shorter repeat of 3 successive numbers I need the first and third position (see first two sequences in ListA above).

I expected the result to be another list. The first two entries for results of `ListA` would be `ListB = {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, ..., etc.}`.  Single numbers in `ListA` with no sequence can be ignored.

Comment: Related: [(46117)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46117/121).  Possible duplicate: [(104672)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104672/121) (not an *exact* duplicate but close enough that I think answers are readily adapted)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's response.  I really enjoyed seeing all the different methods to solve the problem.

Comment: Which solution is likely to be fastest over a long list?

Comment: Although I have not run benchmarks on these specific answers I expect my proposal to be faster than anything that is not compiled as that was my intent in the original Q&A. See [(22419)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22419/121) for one approach if you wish to benchmark these methods yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fn[{{_, fp_}, ___, {_, lp_}}] := Flatten@{fp, lp}
fn[_] := Nothing
fn /@ SplitBy[MapIndexed[List, ListA], First]
```

> {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {18, 48}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100, 
>     249}, {251, 253}, {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {268, 272}, {282, 
>     283}, {285, 286}, {291, 292}, {311, 312}, {315, 316}, {318, 
>     320}, {322, 324}, {327, 328}, {331, 332}, {333, 334}, {337, 
>     338}, {339, 340}, {342, 343}, {352, 355}, {356, 359}}

Comment: This works well, and appears to work quite fast on large data sets.

Comment: @SPIL I bring this up only because you have asked about or commented upon speed multiple times now so it seems like performance is important to you.  My corrected `runs` code is as much as one hundred times faster than this method, on e.g. `ListA = Join @@ (ConstantArray[RandomInteger[99], #] & /@ 
     RandomInteger[{1, 30}, 15000]);`.  I have found it to be faster than anything based on `Split` or `SplitBy`.

Answer (score 9):

In versions 10 and later, you can get the result using a single function `SequencePosition`:

```
repSeqPos = SequencePosition[#, {Repeated[a_, {2, Infinity}]}, Overlaps->False]&;

repSeqPos @ listA
```

> {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {18, 48}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100, 
>     249}, {251, 253}, {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {268, 272}, {282, 
>     283}, {285, 286}, {291, 292}, {311, 312}, {315, 316}, {318, 
>     320}, {322, 324}, {327, 328}, {331, 332}, {333, 334}, {337, 
>     338}, {339, 340}, {342, 343}, {352, 355}, {356, 359}}

Comment: This works perfectly.  But the code becomes very labored and slow as the data set increases in size.

Answer (score 6):

Gives also the start-ends of single-element sublists:

```
pos = Accumulate @ Partition[{1}~Join~(Length /@ Split @ ListA), 2, 1]
```

> {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {17, 17}, {18, 48}, {49, 49}, {50, 
>     50}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100, 249}, {250, 250}, {251, 253}, {254, 
>     254}, {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {261, 261}, {262, 262}, {263, 
>     263}, {264, 264}, {265, 265}, {266, 266}, {267, 267}, {268, 
>     272}, {273, 273}, {274, 274}, {275, 275}, {276, 276}, {277, 
>     277}, {278, 278}, {279, 279}, {280, 280}, {281, 281}, {282, 
>     283}, {284, 284}, {285, 286}, {287, 287}, {288, 288}, {289, 
>     289}, {290, 290}, {291, 292}, {293, 293}, {294, 294}, {295, 
>     295}, {296, 296}, {297, 297}, {298, 298}, {299, 299}, {300, 
>     300}, {301, 301}, {302, 302}, {303, 303}, {304, 304}, {305, 
>     305}, {306, 306}, {307, 307}, {308, 308}, {309, 309}, {310, 
>     310}, {311, 312}, {313, 313}, {314, 314}, {315, 316}, {317, 
>     317}, {318, 320}, {321, 321}, {322, 324}, {325, 325}, {326, 
>     326}, {327, 328}, {329, 329}, {330, 330}, {331, 332}, {333, 
>     334}, {335, 335}, {336, 336}, {337, 338}, {339, 340}, {341, 
>     341}, {342, 343}, {344, 344}, {345, 345}, {346, 346}, {347, 
>     347}, {348, 348}, {349, 349}, {350, 350}, {351, 351}, {352, 
>     355}, {356, 359}, {360, 360}}

Ignoring subsequences of length 1:

```
Select[pos, Differences@# != {0} &]
```

> {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {18, 48}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100, 
>     249}, {251, 253}, {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {268, 272}, {282, 
>     283}, {285, 286}, {291, 292}, {311, 312}, {315, 316}, {318, 
>     320}, {322, 324}, {327, 328}, {331, 332}, {333, 334}, {337, 
>     338}, {339, 340}, {342, 343}, {352, 355}, {356, 359}}

---

Alternatively:

```
pos = MinMax /@ SplitBy[MapIndexed[List, ListA], First][[All, All, 2]]
Select[pos, #[[1]] != #[[2]] &]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility:

```
seqs = {1, 0} + # & /@ Partition[Prepend[Accumulate[Length /@ Split[ListA]], 0], 2, 1];
Pick[seqs, Unequal @@@ seqs]
   {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {18, 48}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100, 249}, {251, 253},
    {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {268, 272}, {282, 283}, {285, 286}, {291, 292}, {311, 312},
    {315, 316}, {318, 320}, {322, 324}, {327, 328}, {331, 332}, {333, 334}, {337, 338},
    {339, 340}, {342, 343}, {352, 355}, {356, 359}}
```

Answer (score 5):

So many ways in *Mathematica* to do anything:

```
ending = Accumulate[Length[#] & /@ Split[ListA]];
starting = Flatten[{1, ending[[1 ;; Length[ending] - 1]] + 1}];
Select[Transpose[{starting, ending}], #[[2]] - #[[1]] > 0 &]
```

> {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {18, 48}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100,
>   249}, {251, 253}, {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {268, 272}, {282,    283},
>   {285, 286}, {291, 292}, {311, 312}, {315, 316}, {318,    320}, {322,
>   324}, {327, 328}, {331, 332}, {333, 334}, {337,    338}, {339, 340},
>   {342, 343}, {352, 355}, {356, 359}}

Answer (score 5):

***Update:*** revised to return only sequences of length two or greater

I propose a derivative of my answer to [Find continuous sequences inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121)

```
runs[a_List] := 
 Pick[{##}\[Transpose], Unitize @ Subtract[##], 1] &[Prepend[# + 1, 1], 
    Append[#, Length@a]] & @ SparseArray[Differences@a]["AdjacencyLists"]

runs @ ListA // Short
```

> ```
> {{1,10}, {11,13}, {14,16}, <<20>>, {342,343}, {352,355}, {356,359}}
> ```

Comment: Yes this is far faster.   But why does it produce {360, 360} at the end? I need sequences 2 and greater. Please can you help?

Comment: @SPIL Oh, *only* sequences of length two or greater?  Sorry, I missed that detail!  This is giving start/end for *all* runs.  Let me see if I can fix this.

Comment: @SPIL please see my revised answer and let me know if you discover any more problems.  It's not quite as fast as before but still appears to be faster than other methods.

Comment: I'm in v11.0.1.I remember that `SparseArray` object has a propertes `"NonzeroPositions"`,but now seem to change into `MatrixColumns`.So pity.

Comment: @yode Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Are you saying the Property `"NonzeroPositions"` has been removed or replaced in v11?

Comment: Yep,I would have wanted to use it in my answer. :-(

Comment: @yode Surprising!  Would you kindly post the output of `SparseArray[{1}]["Methods"]` from v11?

Comment: Funny,I get it by your code,but I get it before by `SparseArray[{1}]["Properties"]`.But now I [get this](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-12-13-20-23-19.png).And it's seem the `NonzeroPositions` work still.

Comment: @yode Perhaps it still exists but is deprecated, maybe?

Comment: I've found that `"Methods"` tends to return more symbols than `"Properties"`, and not only for `SparseArray[]`, but for most objects that can be queried. I don't know why either.

Comment: @J.M. Not `MeshRegion` and `DateObject` as I know.Can you give some example object you tried?

Comment: @yode, there's `BSplineFunction[]`, `InterpolatingFunction[]`, and `ParametricFunction[]`, off the top of my head.

Comment: @J.M. Good head. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Jim's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133169/8238) encouraged me!

Leaving all the hard work to pattern matching:

```
f[{}, n_] := {{}, {1, 1, n}}
f[{ls___, {st_, ct_, last_}}, last_]:= {ls, {st, ct + 1, last}}
f[{ls___, {st_, st_, last_}}, new_] := {ls, {st + 1, st + 1, new}}
f[{ls___, {st_, ct_, last_}}, new_] := {ls~Append~{st, ct}, {ct + 1, ct + 1, new}}

First@Fold[f, {}, ListA]
```

> {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {18, 48}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100, 
>     249}, {251, 253}, {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {268, 272}, {282, 
>     283}, {285, 286}, {291, 292}, {311, 312}, {315, 316}, {318, 
>     320}, {322, 324}, {327, 328}, {331, 332}, {333, 334}, {337, 
>     338}, {339, 340}, {342, 343}, {352, 355}, {356, 359}}

Answer (score 3):

You my `SplitBy` `Identity` to get the sublist.  Then `FoldList` to get their start and end positions in the list. Finally `Select` those that are longer than one position.

```
Select[Subtract @@ # != 0 &]@
 FoldList[
  Last@#1 + {1, Length@#2} &,
  {0, 0},
  SplitBy[listA, Identity]
  ]
```

> ```
> {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {18, 48}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100, 249}, {251, 253}, 
>  {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {268, 272}, {282, 283}, {285, 286}, {291, 292}, {311, 312}, 
>  {315, 316}, {318, 320}, {322, 324}, {327, 328}, {331, 332}, {333, 334}, {337, 338}, 
>  {339, 340}, {342, 343}, {352, 355}, {356, 359}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
#[[{1, -1}]]&/@ 
 Values[Select[
   PositionIndex[
    Flatten[MapIndexed[First[#2] + #1 &, Unitize[Split[ListA]]]]], 
   Length@# > 1 &]]
```

> {{1,10},{11,13},{14,16},{18,48},{51,88},{89,99},{100,249},{251,253},{255,258},{259,260},{268,272},{282,283},{285,286},{291,292},{311,312},{315,316},{318,320},{322,324},{327,328},{331,332},{333,334},{337,338},{339,340},{342,343},{352,355},{356,359}}

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun here is a slightly contrived [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html) method based on [Finding a subsequence in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/941/121).

```
ReplaceList[ListA,
  {P___, Q : Repeated[q_, {2, ∞}], Except[q_], ___} /; 
    Last[{P}] =!= q :>
      Length[{P}] + {1, Length[{Q}]}
]
```

> ```
> {{1, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 16}, {18, 48}, {51, 88}, {89, 99}, {100, 249}, {251, 
>   253}, {255, 258}, {259, 260}, {268, 272}, {282, 283}, {285, 286}, {291, 
>   292}, {311, 312}, {315, 316}, {318, 320}, {322, 324}, {327, 328}, {331, 
>   332}, {333, 334}, {337, 338}, {339, 340}, {342, 343}, {352, 355}, {356, 359}}
> ```

The `Last[{P}] =!= q` part is ugly and throws a warning but I couldn't think of better.