# How to find all the positions of max value of a list efficiently?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

For Example, 
`list=RandomInteger[{1,100},2000]`.
Yes,I know  `Position[list,Max[list]]` can do. 
But it's based on pattern matching! 
`Ordering[list,-1]` could find one position but not all. 
So how to find all the positions of max value of `list` in a more efficient way?Thank you.

Comment: `list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^7]; Position[list, Max[list]] // AbsoluteTiming // First` only takes 0.8220470second

Comment: @Shutao Tang  Similar topic to find one position of max value of a matrix was discussed in Baidu Tieba. http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3717089683 (*I notice that you are a Chinese student.*) But I am not satisfied by the code posted by xzcyr which uses `Ordering` and only finds one position,so I come to here to ask experts.

Comment: Related: [(900)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900/121),
[(1342)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1342/121)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A fast uncompiled alternative without pattern matching is to use the `NonzeroPositions` property of `SparseArray`, as long as you're dealing with numerical data.

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^7];

SparseArray[Unitize[list - Max[list]] - 1]["NonzeroPositions"]; // RepeatedTiming
(* 0.0855 *)

Position[list, Max[list]] // RepeatedTiming
(* 0.509 *)

compPos[list, Max[list]] // RepeatedTiming (* Marius' solution *)
(* 0.0366 *)

SparseArray[Unitize[list - Max[list]], Automatic, 1][
   "NonzeroPositions"]; // RepeatedTiming (* MichaelE2's solutions *)
(* 0.0663 *)
```

Comment: Is it possible to  extend this solution to 2-D?

Comment: @ShutaoTang It already works in 2D.

Comment: `SparseArray[Unitize[list - Max[list]], Automatic, 1]["NonzeroPositions"]` is a little faster.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, added it to the list.

Answer (score 19):

For a 1D list you can also use

```
Pick[Range@Length@list, list, Max@list]
```

Comment: +1 For me this is the fastest here without requiring a compile, although probably takes more memory because of the range. Weird though, because it's still doing pattern matching yet much faster than Position

Comment: @Histograms, `Pick` has been shown to often be _very_ fast, e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/select-performance). The only thing beating it in that case is compiled `Select`, which is basically what I implemented in my answer.

Comment: @Histograms Since version 8 `Pick` is optimized for packed arrays, bypassing pattern matching in a case like this.  See: [(11)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11/121)

Answer (score 13):

For a one-dimensional list:

```
compPos = 
 Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}, {max, _Integer}},
  Block[{copy = list, i = 1},
   Do[
    If[
     list[[j]] == max, copy[[i++]] = j],
    {j, Length[list]}];
   copy[[1 ;; i - 1]]
  ], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ];
```

Though I think `Position` is a good non-compiled alternative in this case, since the "pattern" you use is a number. There won't be any useless matches to this pattern.

#### Performance Test

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^7];
Position[list, Max[list]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.8220470
> ```

```
compPos[list, Max[list]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0830048
> ```

Obviously, *10 times speed-up*

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) `Position` itself for machine types (e.g. Integer or Real):

```
posmax = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}}, Position[list, Max@list] ];
```

Performance:

```
x = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^7];

Position[x, Max@x] // Timing // First

posmax[x] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.44754
>
> 0.0736
> ```

With a C compiler this should be faster still; I'll find out in a few minutes if the Microsoft compiler installs correctly.

Comment: I have read every Q&A I can find about installing a C compiler but I still get "Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function." -- I am using Mathematica 10.1 under Windows 7 x64.  If anyone can help me with this problem please comment here.

Comment: I tried to get a Borland C++ compiler to work, with no luck as well. I wanted to mention something I found useful, in case you haven't come across it. I have been playing with the `CreateExecutable` function from the "CCompilerDriver\`GenericCCompiler\` package. Two options have been instructive: `"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print` and `"CleanIntermediate" -> False`. The shell output function allowed me to see what the compiler was complaining about (I discovered that the command line generated for the compiler was wrong); leaving the intermediate files behind also helped. No joy yet though...

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the ideas.  ShellOutputFunction helps, showing that there seem to be missing `.bat` files in the installation for the x64 compilers, despite the x64 compilers themselves being present.  I'm not sure what to make of that.  If I'm going to have to debug an installation I think I'd rather go with GCC; I installed the Microsoft SDK because was supposed to be the most pain-free solution.

Comment: Installing VisualStudio2013 may help...I seldom use C complier-though I know that compilefunction will run faster.

Comment: Oddly, I found no improvement compiling to C.  I suppose that means that the compiled versions of `Max` and  `Position` are already optimal. (Mac OS)  +1 of course.

Comment: Which SDK version did you download?

Comment: @Oleksandr "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (ISO)" Version 7.1 5/19/2010, x64 ISO: GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso -- apparently as installed I am missing `vcvars64.bat` among others.

Comment: Hmm. Did you have .Net framework 4 installed before installing the compilers? This issue arose in [(5487)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/). See also [some notes](http://pastebin.com/PDHgxb7y) I wrote for myself on the subject.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I had/have "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2" installed according to the Add/Remove Programs dialog.  Thanks, I'll take a look at the notes when I have time.

Comment: Please note that the versions of .Net framework do not supersede each other! On my computer I have versions 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, 3.5 SP1, and 4 installed (so far I found no reason to install 4.5). Version 4.5 is not sufficient as a replacement for version 4.0.

Comment: @OleksandrR.  I did not realize this.  I suppose that is the explanation.  Nevertheless I am a bit soured to a nearly 1GB compiler that needs yet more libraries.  Have you every tried to configure GCC for Mathematica under Windows?

Comment: Yes, I use MinGW-w64 myself. I am not sure how it is in version 10, but in versions 8 and 9 you have to modify the `CCompilerDriver\`` package and rebuild the link libraries to make it work. It is not straightforward. But I will help you to do it if you like.

Comment: @Oleksandr I certainly would like your help but I don't have the time or focus to do it tonight.  If you feel like writing up instructions go ahead, otherwise contact me on another day when you have some spare time.  Thanks!

Comment: I wrote [some instructions](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Jun/msg00323.html) on *MathGroup* but was purposely vague as modifying *Mathematica* strictly contravenes the licence. If you want more detail, let me know and we will discuss it somewhere convenient.

Answer (score 9):

My proposal:

```
Nearest[list -> Automatic, Max[list], {All, 0.5}]
```

Among non-C solutions, it's slightly faster than [Pickett's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/pickett), but slower than [Simon Woods's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods).

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^7];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];

Nearest[list -> Automatic, Max[list], {All, 0.5}] // AccurateTiming
SparseArray[Unitize[list - Max[list]] - 1]["NonzeroPositions"] // AccurateTiming (* P. *)
Pick[Range@Length@list, list, Max@list] // AccurateTiming                       (* S.W. *)
(*
  0.0925321
  0.121649
  0.0403738
*)
```

I have to say I was surprised, because I'd become accustomed to the superiority of `SparseArray`.  But `Nearest` has been improved in V10.  For instance, it takes 2.5 sec on my machine in V9.0.1!!  Wow.

Comment: `Nearest[list -> Automatic, Max[list], {All, 0.5}]` gives the warning information in V8

Comment: @ShutaoTang I don't see why one would use this pre-V10, though.  Try replacing `All` by `Length@list`.  (I don't have V8 to debug.)

Comment: This time it works well in V8, thks a lot:-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang You're welcome.  I assume it's slow, like in V9?

Comment: In V8, @Michael E2, `Nearest[list -> Automatic, 
   Max[list], {Length@list, 0.5}]; // AbsoluteTiming` takes `4.1367188 sec`. Now, I cannot test it in V9 owing to that my OS didn't install V9.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind using an undocumented internal function, you could try using `` Random`Private`PositionsOf ``:

```
list = RandomInteger[100, 10^7];

r1 = Random`Private`PositionsOf[list, Max[list]]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Pick[Range@Length@list, list, Max@list]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.011, Null}
>
> {0.037, Null}
>
> True

Comment: How did this have zero votes 'til now? +1!  Although in v10.1 it doesn't yet have the speed.

Answer (score 4):

I think this works `Ordering[dat, -Count[dat, Max[dat]]]` but it is actually slower than `Position[dat,Max[dat]]`

This also works, but again, it's still slower

```
pos1[list_, max_] := Block[{i = 1, l = Length[list]},
  Last[Reap[While[i <= l,
  If[list[[i]] == max, CompoundExpression[Sow[i], i++], i++]]]]]
```

... unfortunately so is this more compact solution

```
pos2[list_, max_] := MapIndexed[If[#==max,Sow@#2,##&[]]&,list]
```

You could try compiling them; I can't use `Compile` with `CompilationTarget->"C"` on my system for various reasons. I'd just stick with using `Position`.

Answer (score 1):

Since V 13.2 we have `PositionLargest` and `PositionSmallest`

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 2000];

PositionLargest[list]
```

{55, 99, 248, 614, 654, 749, 894, 967, 1029, 1144, 1209, 1392, 1866, 1893, 1932}

It is comparatively fast:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^7];

PositionLargest[list]; // Timing // First
```

0.173024

```
Position[list, Max @ list] // Timing // First
```

0.346482

Answer (score 1):

**Using `PositionIndex`:** (introduced 9th July 2014)

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10^7];
PositionIndex[list][Max[list]]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.155408, Null}