# How to pick an element of a row corresponding to the minimum in a particular column?

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I find what value in column 1 of my list corresponds to the minimum value in column 2?

Comment: What _value_ or what _position_?

Comment: Hi @belisarius, I just saw this. This is my first use of this website, and so far it is very helpful. I did need to know the value, and now I'd also like to find out how to find the position in the array. Thank you!

Comment: Related: [(900)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900/121)

Answer (score 15):

`Pick[]` is one way to go about it:

```
test = {{15, 11}, {5, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 5}, {13, 15}, {6, 10}, {8, 15}, {0, 2},
        {10, 13}, {2, 5}};

Pick[#1, #2, Min[#2]] & @@ Transpose[test]
   {0}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I used your method and it worked!

Comment: Can I also find which item in the array the minimum value is? How?

Comment: @Michelle did you read my comment right under your question?

Comment: Hi @belisarius, I just saw it. This is my first visit to the website and I did not at first notice that I needed to "expand" the new comments.

Comment: @Michelle Welcome! It takes some time to get used to the features of the site. Feel free to ask

Comment: @belisarius thank you! I also need to know the position in the array that corresponds to the minimum value in the 2nd column. I have tried many things and cannot figure it out. I might be making a small mistake, as a Junior in Physics I am not familiar with Mathematica yet.

Comment: @Michelle `{Min[#2], Position[#1, Min[#2]]} & @@ Transpose[test]`

Comment: @Michelle, "Can I also find which item in the array the minimum value is?" - `Pick[Thread[{#1, #2}], #2, Min[#2]] & @@ Transpose[test]` and `Pick[#, #[[All, 2]], Min[#[[All, 2]]]] &[test]` are two ways to do it. You get a $p\times 2$ array, where $p$ is the number of results returned; for each entry, the second component is the minimum value in the second column, and the first component is the corresponding entry in the first column.

Comment: I interpreted "corresponds to" as meaning equals!

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**

In my earlier submission, I mistakenly took "corresponds to" as meaning "has the same value as".  Here I interpret "corresponds to" as "occupies the same row as".
This variation relies on `Position`, as before.

```
#1[[Position[#2, Min@#2][[1, 1]]]] & @@ Transpose@t
```

---

**Exemplification**

`t` happens to be 15x7:

```
t={{0, 10, 4, 19, 1, 3, 2}, {3, 18, 1, 12, 7, 14, 16}, {11, 8, 17, 18, 7, 12, 17}, {12, 16, 0, 16, 8, 3, 11}, {8, 2, 14, 3, 18, 7, 6}, {5, 15, 14, 9, 9, 3, 2}, {9, 10, 17, 6, 19, 14, 0}, {3, 5, 18, 11, 10, 12, 6}, {7, 13, 7, 13, 16, 14, 16}, {14, 12, 4, 19, 18, 20, 7}, {18,3, 19, 15, 16, 18, 8}, {1, 18, 5, 11, 3, 5, 2}, {16, 11, 7, 11, 2, 2, 19}, {1, 8, 7, 7, 15, 1, 20}, {11, 9, 2, 7, 2, 18, 4}}
```

The  lowest value in column 2 is `2`. It sits next to the value `8` in column one.

```
#1[[Position[#2, Min@#2][[1, 1]]]] & @@ Transpose@t
```

> 8

[image: results]

**Explanation**

Let's explain what the following does:

```
#1[[Position[#2, Min@#2][[1, 1]]]]
```

First note that `Min@#2`returns the minimum value in the second column: `2`

Now plug `2` into

```
Position[#2, Min@#2][[1, 1]]
```

obtaining

```
Position[#2, 2][[1, 1]]
```

returning `5'.

Substituting again, `#1[[5]]` returns the value the cell at column 1, row 5:

> 8

Answer (score 4):

Here's a straightforward way using `Cases`:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {2, 4}}; (* example list *)
With[{min = Min@#[[All, 2]]}, Cases[#, {x_, min} :> x]] &@list
(* {3, 4} *)
```

You can also use `Select` or `Pick`, depending on the usage. You should read through the documentation to see how to use them.

Comment: Thank you very much I used Pick[] and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way, stealing @J.M's test list

```
test = {{15, 11}, {5, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 5}, {13, 15}, {6, 10}, {8, 15}, {0, 2},
        {10, 13}, {2, 5}};

First@Extract[test, test~Reverse~2~Ordering~1]
```

> 0

Remove `First` to see the whole row

Or probably faster is

```
Extract[#1, #2~Ordering~1] & @@ Transpose[test]
```

Comment: Damn, you win the cool factor.

Comment: Rojo~Reverse~Upvote

Comment: @belisarius, haha, I almost did it on purpose waiting for your comment

Comment: I knew. I tried hard not to fail you

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

Not sure about "asking" but here's a way to do it.

I'll build some data for an example:

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}]
```

And to find the value in the position in column 1 of the minimum of column 2:

```
a[[Flatten[Position[a[[All, 2]], Min[a[[All, 2]]]]], 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Beware of the possibility of multiple minima, especially in long lists of discrete elements. I think for a novice J.M.'s solution is the more instructive. 
I have changed its first element to demonstrate two identical minima:

```
test = {{15, 2}, {5, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 5}, {13, 15}, {6, 10}, {8, 15}, {0, 2}, {10, 13}, {2, 5}};

Pick[#1, #2, Min[#2]] & @@ Transpose[test]

out: {15, 0}
```

Finding the position of the minimum/minima:

```
min = Min@test[[All, 2]]
pos = Position[test[[All, 2]], min]

out: 2
out: {{1}, {8}}
```

In order to grab the corresponding values in Col. 1, the "pos" list must be Flattened first:

```
test[[Flatten@pos, 1]]

out: {15, 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
test = {{15, 11}, {5, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 5}, {13, 15}, {6, 10}, {8, 15},
    {0,2}, {10, 13}, {2, 5}};
```

variations with `Ordering` in Rojo's answer using `Part` instead of `Extract`:

```
test[[Ordering[test[[All, 2]], 1]]][[1, 1]]
```

or

```
First[#[[1]][[Ordering[#[[2]], 1]]] &[Transpose[test]]]
```

or

```
test[[Ordering[test, 1, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]]][[1, 1]]
(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using two newer functions:

```
test = {{15, 11}, {5, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 5}, {13, 15}, {6, 10}, {8, 15}, {0, 2}, {10, 13}, {2, 5}};

MinimalBy[test, Last][[1, 1]]
```

0

```
First @ Extract[PositionSmallest[Last /@ test]] @ test
```

0

`MinimalBy` since V 10.3

`PositionSmallest` since V 13.2

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using `Query` and `SelectFirst`:

```
f[mat_] := mat // Query[SelectFirst[#[[2]] == Min[mat[[All, 2]]] &], 1]
```

Testing `f`:

```
test = {{15, 11}, {5, 14}, {2, 13}, {3, 5}, {13, 15}, 
       {6, 10}, {8, 15}, {0, 2},{10, 13}, {2, 5}};

t={{0, 10, 4, 19, 1, 3, 2}, {3, 18, 1, 12, 7, 14, 16}, {11, 8, 17, 18, 7, 12, 17}, 
  {12, 16, 0, 16, 8, 3, 11}, {8, 2, 14, 3, 18, 7, 6}, {5, 15, 14, 9, 9, 3, 2}, 
  {9, 10, 17, 6, 19, 14, 0}, {3, 5, 18, 11, 10, 12, 6}, {7, 13, 7, 13, 16, 14, 16}, 
  {14, 12, 4, 19, 18, 20, 7}, {18,3, 19, 15, 16, 18, 8}, {1, 18, 5, 11, 3, 5, 2}, 
  {16, 11, 7, 11, 2, 2, 19}, {1, 8, 7, 7, 15, 1, 20}, {11, 9, 2, 7, 2, 18, 4}};

  f /@ {test, t}

  (*{0, 8}*)
```