# Which integration strategy to use for this product of polynomials?

Tags: numerical-integration

What would be the ideal integration strategy for a function like this: $$f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N)=\prod_{i=1}^Nx_i^{c_i}\Theta(x_i-p_i)$$ where $x_i,p_i\in \mathbb{R}$, $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function and $c_i\in \mathbb{N}^+$ when trying to integrate something like $$\int_0^1\mathrm{d}x_1\int_0^{1-x_1}\mathrm{d}x_2\dots\int_0^{1-x_1-x_2\dots-x_{N-1}}\mathrm{d}x_Nf(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N)?$$

**Edit:** $N$ is usually rather small, namely $N<10$; the $c_i$, however, can be of the order of $10^2$.

**Edit 2:** I am aware that this question is quite general, but maybe there are general rules how to `NIntegrate` monotonous functions like this.

**Edit 3:** An example for $f$ would be

```
f[x1_,x2_,x3_] = x1^23 x2^45 x3^123 HeavisideTheta[ x1-1/20 ] HeavisideTheta[ x2-1/20 ]
```

**Edit 4:** Since I was apparently confusing some people, here's roughly what I want to compute:

```
NIntegrate[f[r1, r2, r3], {r1, 0, 1}, {r2, 0, 1 - r1}, {r3, 0, 1 - r1 - r2}]
```

This gives a result `(2.8227403075197916*^-78)` but also states:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small

My question is: What is the fastest and most robust [NIntegrate Integration Strategy](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#137878679) when I wand to do this with arbirtary $1<N<10$ and $\left\{c_i\right\}$?

Comment: Give a Mathematica definition of your function $f$ for $N<10$. It shows what you have tried already...

Comment: Perhaps if you just care to mention the specific problem you are facing ...

Comment: What do you mean by "integration strategy"? (I mean, what are you really asking? how to construct the arguments of `Integrate[]`?) I imagine you need this analytically, right?

Comment: @acl I mean which one of those is fastest/most accurate: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#137878679

Comment: OK I see, I had interpreted this to be about `Integrate`; with the clarification it's unambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Introductory remarks

First, the high degree of the monomial leads to a very small integral.  This tricks *Mathematica's* heuristic into thinking the integral might be zero and that the small value is a by-product of numerical error.  The integrand is essential a polynomial, so the warning message is not particularly worrisome.

Second, `Boole` gets special treatment by `NIntegrate` and is better to use than `HeavisideTheta` in this case. So this definition would work faster:

```
f2[x1_, x2_, x3_] := x1^23 x2^45 x3^123 Boole[x1 >= 1/20 && x2 >= 1/20]
```

Basically, the `Boole`/`HeavisideTheta` factors simply restrict the domain.  It seems better to just calculate the actual domain and omit those factors.  `Reduce` can do this.  Use strict inequalities to avoid cases for the bounding surfaces of the region.

```
Reduce[And @@ Cases[f[r1, r2, r3], HeavisideTheta[e_] :> e > 0] && 
   0 < r1 < 1 && 0 < r2 < 1 - r1 && 0 < r3 < 1 - r1 - r2,
 {r1, r2, r3}  (* order according to the reverse order in N/Integrate *)
 ]
(* 1/20 < r1 < 19/20 && 1/20 < r2 < 1 - r1 && 0 < r3 < 1 - r1 - r2 *)
```

We can convert this expression to an integration domain with this:

```
domain = Sequence @@ 
  Cases[List @@ 
    Reduce[And @@ Cases[ff @@ vars[3], HeavisideTheta[e_] :> e > 0] &&
       0 < r[1] < 1 && 0 < r[2] < 1 - r[1] && 0 < r[3] < 1 - r[1] - r[2],
    Reverse@vars[3]],   (* pick order according to decreasing degree *)
   h_[a_, ___, b : Alternatives @@ vars[3], ___, c_] :> {b, a, c}
   ]
(* Sequence[{r3, 0, 9/10}, {r2, 1/20, 1/20 (19 - 20 r3)}, {r1, 1/20, 1 - r2 - r3}] *)
```

Over this region, we can integrate using the integrand

```
f0[x1_, x2_, x3_] := x1^23 x2^45 x3^123
```

Next, high-dimensional integrals take a long time.  If there are 100 sample points in each direction, a three-dimensional integral will require 1,000,000 function evaluations.  One might try to deal with this by demanding less accuracy, but there are limits.  For a ten-dimensional integral, sampling on a 10-point tensor grid leads to $10^{10}$ function evaluations.

With the integrand and integration domain in this shape, there are two approaches to consider, symbolic integration and numerical integration.

[Some timings through the [`timeAvg`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/900/how-to-find-rows-that-have-maximum-value/901#901) function.  Code at end.)

#### Symbolic integration

The straightforward way takes a while:

```
exact = Integrate[f0[r1, r2, r3], Evaluate@domain]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
N[exact, 30]
(*
  39.832165
  2.82584140053428314442718045642*10^-78
*)
```

Iterating single integrals is faster:

```
Fold[Integrate, f0[r1, r2, r3], Reverse@{domain}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*
  4.913279
*)
```

*Note:* The order of the variables in `domain` matters.  If instead of `Reverse @ vars[3]` in the `Reduce` command that computes `domain` above, we were to put simply `vars[3]`, then the iterated `Integrate` takes 10+ seconds.

#### Numerical integration

The default method of `NIntegrate` is not that bad, with a precision of just under 9 digits or about half of `MachinePrecision`:

```
res = NIntegrate[f0[r1, r2, r3], Evaluate@domain]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(res - exact) / exact
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: ...

```
(*
  1.409120
  2.7603*10^-9
*)
```

There are two rules worth considering because they can be exact on polynomials, `"GaussKronrodRule"` and `"ClenshawCurtisRule"`.  (See [`tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html).)  There is also the `"LobattoKronrodRule"`, but I'll leave that aside; it's similar in performance to `"GaussKronrodRule"` but not exact.  Each has a `"Points"` suboption that controls the order of the rule.  By setting this to appropriate values, one can speed up the convergence.  By default, `NIntegrate` will use the `"CartesianRule"` on multidimensional integrals and one can specify an integration rule for each dimension, and for each one can specify a value for `"Points"` that is appropriate to the degree of the integrand with respect to that variable. To get an exact result one uses a setting of roughly 1/3 the degree for Gauss-Kronrod and 1/2 for Clenshaw-Curtis; in practice, one should set them lower for the sake of speed.
Gauss-Kronrod works faster with the default `"GlobalAdaptive"` strategy and
Clenshaw-Curtis works faster with the `"LocalAdaptive"` strategy.  (See [`tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html)

**Gauss-Kronrod**:

```
Grid@Prepend[
  Table[
   Flatten@{pts,
     res = NIntegrate @@ {f0[r1, r2, r3], domain, 
           Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> pts}}; // timeAvg,
     res, (res - exact)/exact},
   {pts, 5, 10}
   ],
  {"Points", "Timing", "Integral", "% Error"}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Clenshaw-Curtis**:

```
Grid@Prepend[
  Table[
   Flatten@{pts,
     res = NIntegrate @@ {f0 @@ vars[3], domain, 
          Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", 
            Method -> {"ClenshawCurtisRule", "Points" -> pts}}}; // timeAvg,
     res, (res - exact)/exact},
   {pts, 5, 35, 5}
   ],
  {"Points", "Timing", "Integral", "% Error"}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see that Clenshaw-Curtis is faster (see next example) for less precision (`"Points" -> 15`), which might make an okay estimate in some cases, than Gauss-Kronrod, but Gauss-Kronrod is faster for higher precisions.

**Gauss-Kronrod with `"LocalAdaptive"` varying `"Points"`**

We get an improvement with increasing the points for the higher degree variables and using the `"LocalAdaptive"` strategy.  It seems for both the Gauss-Kronrod and Clenshaw-Curtis rules, `"LocalAdaptive"` results in much less recursive subdivision.  This makes it faster, but also you cannot be as certain of the error. (`PrecisionGoal` seems to make no difference.)

```
Grid@Prepend[
  Table[
   Flatten@{StandardForm@{16 + pts, 8 + pts, pts},
     res = NIntegrate @@ {f0[r1, r2, r3], domain,
          Method -> {"LocalAdaptive",
            Method -> {"CartesianRule",
              Method -> {
                {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 18 + pts},
                {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 6 + pts},
                {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> pts}}}}}; // 
      timeAvg,
     res, (res - exact)/exact},
   {pts, 5, 10}
   ],
  {"Points", "Timing", "Integral", "% Error"}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Manual numerical integration

One can get a bit more speed by constructing a integrator specifically for this problem.  It is amenable to this because the Gauss-Kronrod is a good way to integrate monomials and `NIntegrate` will supply all the data you need to do it.  From the tutorial [`tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html), you can see how to perform the time-integration step.  After determining how many `"Points"` you want for each dimension and what , then

```
{absc, weights, errweights} = NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[npoints, precision]
```

returns the abcissas, the weights, and the error weights for the integral over the interval $[0,1]$. (For an integral over another interval, one can perform a substitution to transform the integral into this form.)  Then the integral can be computed as

```
integral = (f /@ absc) . weights
```

For a multidimensional integral, one does a similar thing.  Transform the integral to one over $[0,1]^n$. Then form Cartesian products of the abcissas and of the weights.  One can use different numbers of `npoints` for each dimension.  Next evaluate the function at the abcissas, multiply by the corresponding weights, and total up the result.

The function `intrule[degrees, parameters, opts]` (code below) does that.  The argument `degrees` is a list of degrees of the variables of the monomial and `parameters` are the $p_i$ in the OP's question.  It does no recursive subdivision or error tracking.  For `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` it compiles the transformed integrand and uses packed arrays for speed.  (It will also work efficiently with arbitrary precision numbers.)  It computes the number of `"Points"` needed for an exact integral. The option `"Scale"` multiplies these numbers to yield a faster but less accurate result.  The setting `MinPoints -> Automatic` prevents the smallest value for `"Points"` from being scaled -- this greatly improves the accuracy on the OP's example, at least.  (When the numbers of `"Points"` is small, the error is sensitive to scaling.)

```
Grid@Prepend[
  Table[
   {sc,
    res = intrule[{23, 45, 123}, {1/20, 1/20, 0},
        Method -> "GaussKronrodRule",
        Scale -> sc, MinPoints -> Automatic, 
        WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]; // timeAvg,
    res, (res - exact)/exact},
   {sc, 0.5, 1., 0.1}
   ],
  {"Scale", "Timing", "Integral", "% Error"}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For `"Scale" -> 1` there should be no truncation error; the error you see is round-off error.  For scales above about 0.8, the truncation error on this example is less than `MachinePrecision`.

#### Code dump

[`timeAvg`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/900/how-to-find-rows-that-have-maximum-value/901#901):

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ AbsoluteTiming@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}];
```

'intrule':

Please forgive for not having time to explain all the code.  It kept growing because the `NIntegrate` framework made it easy to keep extending features.  A generic description is given above.

```
ClearAll[intrule];
ClearAll["intrule`*"];

Options[intrule] = {WorkingPrecision -> 20, Scale -> 1, 
   MinPoints -> 2, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"};

intrule`points[deg_, "GaussKronrodRule"] := deg/3;
intrule`points[deg_, "LobattoKronrodRule"] := 1 + deg/3;
intrule`points[deg_, "ClenshawCurtisRule"] := (1 + deg)/2;
intrule`points[deg_List, scale_, min_, method_] := 
  With[{points0 = intrule`points[#, method] & /@ deg}, 
   Ceiling[Max[scale #, min /. Automatic -> Min[points0, 2]]] & /@ 
    points0];
intrule`ruledata["GaussKronrodRule"] := 
  NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData;
intrule`ruledata["LobattoKronrodRule"] := 
  NIntegrate`LobattoKronrodRuleData;
intrule`ruledata["ClenshawCurtisRule"] := 
  NIntegrate`ClenshawCurtisRuleData;

intrule[deg_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &), 
   param_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), OptionsPattern[]] /; 
  Length[deg] == Length[param] :=

 Module[{integrand, integrandC, domain, dim, vars0, order, map, 
   points, absc, weights, errweights, sample, w, vals},
  order = Ordering[deg, All, Greater];
  vars0 = Array[K, dim = Length[deg]][[order]];
  domain = Cases[List @@ Reduce[
      And @@ Thread[vars0 - param > 0] && 
       And @@ FoldList[
         0 < #2 < Last[#] - First[Cases[#, Alternatives @@ vars0]] &, 
         0 < First[vars0] < 1,
         Rest[vars0]],
      vars0[[order]]], 
    h_[a_, ___, b : Alternatives @@ vars0, ___, c_] :> {b, a, c}
    ];
  map =    (* transforms the OP's function to a function over the unit cube *)
   Simplify[
    vars0 //. 
     Thread[vars0 -> 
       Table[domain[[order[[i]], {2, 3}]].{1 - t, t} /. 
         t -> Slot[i], {i, Length[deg]}]]
    ];
  integrand = 
   Evaluate[
     Inner[Power, map, deg, Times] Simplify@
       Det@D[map, {Array[Slot, dim]}]] &;
  integrandC = If[OptionValue[WorkingPrecision] === MachinePrecision,
    (* compile if MachinePrecision *)
    Compile @@ {vars0, integrand @@ vars0,
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True},
    integrand];
  points = 
   With[{points0 = 
      intrule`points[Exponent[integrand @@ vars0, #], 
         OptionValue[Method]] & /@ vars0}, 
    Ceiling[Max[OptionValue[Scale] #, 
        OptionValue[MinPoints] /. Automatic -> Min[points0], 2]] & /@ 
     points0];
  Do[{absc[n], weights[n]} = 
    Developer`ToPackedArray /@    (* a quick no-op if not MachinePrecision *)
     Most@intrule`ruledata[OptionValue[Method]][n, 
       OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]],
   {n, points}];
  sample = Transpose@Tuples[Table[absc[n], {n, points}]]; 
  w = Times @@ Transpose@Tuples[Table[weights[n], {n, points}]];
  vals = integrandC @@ sample;
  vals.w
  ]
```

Comment: With respect to why the Gaussian and Clenshaw-Curtis quadratures give results of comparable accuracy, see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/060659831).