# extracting the rows of a matrix satisfying a condition (e.g. all elements negative)

Tags: matrix, filtering

I have a matrix with thousands of rows and want the submatrix comprising the rows of the original matrix that have, e.g. a negative element in column 3. How to do that?

Answer (score 7):

I think this question is reasonably a duplicate of:  [How to find rows that have maximum value?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900/121) (or several similar questions) and I will delete this answer if it is closed as such.  Nevertheless, again for reference:

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = RandomInteger[{-3, 5}, {20, 5}]

Pick[a, Negative @ a[[All, 3]]]
```

> ```
> {{-2, 1, -3, 4, -3}, {-2, 0, -1, -2, 3}, {1, 0, -3, -2, 0}, {2, 0, -3, 0, -1},
>  {0, 2, -2, 2, -1}, {0, -2, -3, 1, 1}, {-2, 2, -1, 4, 5}, {0, -1, -2, -2, 3},
>  {2, 3, -3, 4, -2}, {0, -2, -1, 2, 5}, {1, 4, -3, 4, 4}}
> ```

Faster in versions 8+ should be to use `UnitStep`, due to packed array optimizations:

```
Pick[a, UnitStep @ a[[All, 3]], 0]
```

In version 7 optimal speed may be had with:

```
a[[SparseArray[BitXor[UnitStep @ a[[All, 3]], 1]]["AdjacencyLists"]]]
```

---

Timings compared to other methods proposed, in version 7:

```
a = RandomInteger[{-3, 5}, {1500000, 5}];

Pick[a, Negative @ a[[All, 3]]] // Timing // First

a[[SparseArray[BitXor[UnitStep @ a[[All, 3]], 1]]["AdjacencyLists"]]] // Timing // First

(col3 = a[[All, 3]]; rowsToGet = Flatten[Position[col3, _?((# < 0) &)]]; a[[rowsToGet]]) //
   Timing // First

Select[a, #[[3]] < 0 &] // Timing // First
```

> 0.234
>
> 0.031
>
> 0.905
>
> 1.17

Comment: I'm curious, what computer do you run? For `Pick` picks a second almost on my i7 (+ Win7 and Mma 9). Can I tweak my system any towards the performance of yours? Another slower method, by a factor of 3.5 with my timing, is to: `Scan` with *levelspec* `{-2}` and `Sow` rows with negative third element.

Comment: @BoLe I use an i5-2500K running at a maximum (single core) of 4.6 GHz.  I know there have been changes to `Pick` since version 7 but I thought they would make things faster rather than slower.

Comment: @BoLe I added two new methods optimized for speed.  Please try both and let me know how they perform.  I expect `Pick[a, UnitStep @ a[[All, 3]], 0]` to be best on v9.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I get (on v9.0.0) {1.896415, 0.146656, 3.255081, 3.815207} for your 4 tested values and 0.051483 for Pick[a, UnitStep @ a[[All, 3]]]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It must be clocking and a newer model I guess, mine is a bit old already (2009) and running at 2.93 GHz. My times are `{0.952, 0.0780, 1.84, 2.04}` which make approximately same ratios as yours, somewhere 10 : 1 : 25 : 30. P.S. `Pick` with `UnitStep` is the fastest here with 0.047.

Comment: @BoLe I have to remember not to write code I don't test as I usually make mistakes; please try the corrected version: `Pick[a, UnitStep @ a[[All, 3]], 0]` and tell me how it performs.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jacob You too, if interested.

Comment: @Jacob should have been `Pick[..., 0]` - I just can't get it right tonight.  I'm going to do something else.

Comment: 0.113797 then :). Take it easy(?)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard 0.093601

Answer (score 4):

```
m  = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}];
m1 = Select[m, #[[3]] < 0 &];
```

Show it:

```
ArrayPlot[#, ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 0 -> Blue, -1 -> Yellow, _ -> Gray}] & /@ {m, m1}
```

[image]