# How do I find the maximum value from the given set of data?

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have a set of data like `{{x1, y1},{x2, y2}, ...,{xn, yn}}`.
From this data can I find the value of `x` for which `y` is maximum.
Is it is possible using *Mathemamtica 9.0*?

Comment: One way will be `First@Sort[list, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &][[1]]`. Where `list = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {xn, yn}}`

Comment: Look up `Ordering`.

Answer (score 5):

`Transpose[list][[2]]` contains all the y values in the list, so you can find the max of these and then locate where this occurs using `Position`

```
Position[y = Transpose[list][[2]], Max[y]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sort[list, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &][[1, 1]]
```

This will give you the value of `x` for which `y` is maximum. But if you also want the value of `y` then do:

```
Sort[list, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &][[1]]
```

Comment: It's basically the same so I'm posting it here: `SortBy[list, Last][[-1, 1]]`

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to allow for duplicate (repeated) maximum values this question is a duplicate of:
[How to find rows that have maximum value?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900/121)

Otherwise I suggest you use `Ordering` as proposed by Ray Koopman:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {50, 2}];
# ~Extract~ Ordering[#2, {-1}] & @@ Transpose[data]
```

Comment: I don't understand why this had not been upvoted before.

Answer (score 3):

There is a much neater way of doing this in *Mathematica* v10 onwards, using `MaximalBy`. Example:

```
lis = { {x1, 10}, {x2, 3}, {x3, 50}, {x4, 20} };

MaximalBy[lis, Last]
```

returns:

```
{{x3, 50}}
```

Comment: Especially slick to use the operator form: `MaximalBy[Last]@list`

Answer (score 2):

If speed is a concern for a large list, try`Pick`as in

```
Pick[list[[All, 1]], list[[All, 2]], Max[list[[All, 2]]]]
```

That is, choose from the list of x values,`list[[All,1]],`where in the list of y values,`list[[All,2]],`y is maximum. I've found array subscripts like`...[[All,...]]`to be fast compared to`Transpose`.

Answer (score 1):

Another fun alternative:

```
list = {{x1, 10}, {x2, 3}, {x3, 50}, {x4, 20}};

Fold[If[#1[[2]] > #2[[2]], #1, #2] &, First@list, Rest@list]
```

A shorter version of the same can be:

```
Fold[If[#1[[2]] > #2[[2]], #1, #2] &, list]
```

> {x3, 50}

---

*Explanation*

Roughly speaking, goes through the list element by element, comparing the best answer (i.e. the one with the largest y) found so far with every element in the list in turn. If on comparison, the element being compared to the best answer so far has a larger y, then that's made the new best answer.