# Finding minimum of a list of pairs

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, sorting

Sometimes I need to find the Min of a list, whose elements are lists (say of two elements, a pair). Given that Min does not have the option to indicate a sorting function like Sort, I elaborated the following approaches:

```
Cases[list, {_, Min[#[[2]] & /@ list]}]
Cases[list, {_, Min[list[[All]]]}]
```

First of all, I would like to see from you if there are other, better, methods, and the question is: testing the timing with the following code

```
n = 2000000;
list = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {n}];
Timing[Cases[list, {_, Min[#[[2]] & /@ list]}]]
Timing[Cases[list, {_, Min[list[[All]]]}]]
```

the second method, that seems to be more efficient, sometimes gives no answer, like in the following:

```
0.262798

{1.0473, {{0.631835, 8.48582*10^-7}}}

{0.98226, {}}
```

why?

Comment: Do you have v10? If so, take a look at: `MinimalBy`.

Comment: @Kuba: no, I'm using v8 :/

Comment: closely related topics: [37594](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37594/5478), this is more general [How do I find the elements in a list that return the highest value for a function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2177/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest I can come up with is (by separating finding the minimum second value in each pair):

```
AbsoluteTiming@With[{min = Min@list[[All, 2]]}, Cases[list, {_, min}]]
(* {1.288129, {{0.555911, 1.05947*10^-6}}} *)
```

while `MinimalBy` takes much longer:

```
AbsoluteTiming@MinimalBy[list, #[[2]]&]
(* {2.074207, {{0.555911, 1.05947*10^-6}}} *)
```

Your second line is not giving any result, since you are searching for the smallest value in the whole list (even the first elements), which are just not matching the second element of a pair: `Cases` therefore returns empty.

**Further explorations of timings**

```
AbsoluteTiming@SortBy[list, #[[2]] &][[1]]
AbsoluteTiming@With[{min = Min@list[[All, 2]]}, Cases[list, {_, min}]]
AbsoluteTiming@MinimalBy[list, #[[2]] &]
AbsoluteTiming@Sort[list, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &][[1]]
```

gives:

```
(* SortBy:    {0.539054, {0.592838, 2.90821*10^-7}}   *)
(* Cases:     {1.298130, {{0.592838, 2.90821*10^-7}}} *)
(* MinimalBy: {2.084208, {{0.592838, 2.90821*10^-7}}} *)
(* Sort:      {73.714371, {0.592838, 2.90821*10^-7}}  *)
```

Note the abysmal performance of `Sort` vs. the fastest "built-in" solution in *Mathematica* v10, `SortBy`.

> **However: Mr. Wizard has found a *much* faster method!**
>   See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/2178) for his method, which can be adapted to your case as follows:
>
> `AbsoluteTiming@list[[Ordering[#[[2]] & /@ list, 1]]]
>   (* {0.119012, {{0.592838, 2.90821*10^-7}}} *)`

Comment: Isn't it stupid that `Sort` is faster than `MinimalBy`? `SortBy[list, Last][[1]]`

Comment: @Kuba: Definitely! Also, `SortBy` is at least twice as fast as the `Cases`-approach (and *much* faster than `Sort`). Alas, the questioner only has v8. :(

Comment: Isn't `SortBy` here since V6?

Comment: Thanks, I understood my error, but I cannot understand, from docs, the difference between Timing and AbsoluteTiming.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the second method is failing is because you are looking for a pair whose second element is the minimum over the whole list (including all the first elements). This of course will fail whenever the global minimum is in the first position. 
The proper syntax is

```
Cases[list, {_, Min[list[[All, 2]]]}]
```

The speed improvement, on the other hand, is due to the absence of Map (/@)

```
AbsoluteTiming[Min[list[[All, 2]]]]

{0.023865, 5.98481*10^-7}

AbsoluteTiming[Min[#[[2]] & /@ list]]

{0.151333, 5.98481*10^-7}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapting `listMaxArg` from linked topic seems to be the fastest.

```
list = RandomReal[1, {10^6, 2}];

list[[Ordering[list[[All, 2]], 1]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.010000, {{0.817248, 6.71112*10^-7}}}
> ```

Comment: Yeah, the fastest, I wonder why?