# Find the last element satisfying certain condition in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of numbers and I want to find the last element of it that satisfies certain condition. In this case, the condition is that the number equals 1. I need exactly the position of that element but I don't know how to do it.

I think that this is very basic but I don't know too much about Mathematica. I read the solution given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-find-the-position-of-elements-in-a-list-satisfying-criteria) and tried with

```
Select[x[i], #=1&]
```

But it did not work. Anyone knows something?

Comment: Is this a question about Mathematica or Magma?  This website is exclusively for Mathematica questions, anything else is considered off topic.

Comment: `Last[Position[x,1]]` should suffice (I assume you're asking about *Mathematica* here)...

Comment: Refering to the [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-find-the-position-of-elements-in-a-list-satisfying-criteria) you cited: `Max@Position[x, _?(# == 1 &)]`

Comment: (1) Test equality with `Equal` (`==`), not `Set` (`=`).  (2) It's good to include any error messages you get with the question, usually.

Comment: Since the OP didn't respond for a while, I am going to go ahead and edit out any reference to Magma.  That will make the question on-topic, though possibly not useful to the OP if he really meant Magma.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this will be better in speed as you've said you have a "list of numbers".

```
Length[list]+1-FirstPosition[Reverse@list,1][[1]]
```

The usage of `FirstPosition` may be better in efficiency. :)

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-find-the-position-of-elements-in-a-list-satisfying-criteria) you cited:

```
x = {1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 17};
Max@Position[x, _?(# == 1 &)]
```

> 9

The `Select` approach should use two `=` intead of one:

```
Select[x, # == 1 &]
```

> {1, 1, 1}

but doesn't lead you anywhere as it just selects elements from a list that are equal to one by checking... if they are equal to one. You want to find `Position` of those ones, and specifically find the position of the last one that appears in a list (the last position will also be the biggest number among the list of positions of ones):

```
Last@Position[x,1]
```

or

```
Max@Position[x,1]
```