# Obtaining the position in a list where the i^th element is bigger than the (i+1)^th element

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

My question is very simple but I am not able to find the optimal solution. What I am trying to do is to have a function that give me the position in a list at which the value at position `i` is bigger than at position `i+1.` I need only the first of such term since afterwards, I will commute the two via another a function and then test again if everything is ordered. Basically, I am searching for

```
In[] : findpos[{1,2,3,4,7,4}]
Out [] : 5
```

My current solution is the following

```
findpos[a_] := 
Module[{index = {}}, 
For[i = 1, i <= Length[a] - 1, i++, If[a[[i]] > a[[i + 1]], index = Append[index, i]]]; 
Return[First[index]]]
```

which gives

```
findpos[{1,2,3,4,7,4}]
5
```

I will have to call this function maybe many time, so I would like something which run fast and I am almost convinced that a module + a For loop will not be the optimal solution speaking of computation time. I looked at many other questions somehow related ; especially this one [How to find the position of elements in a list satisfying criteria](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-find-the-position-of-elements-in-a-list-satisfying-criteria)

I think I am searching for something of the form

```
Position[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, _?(# > 7 &)]
```

But who compare two elements instead of each element to a scalar. I tried to adapt it to my case without success. I tried something of the form

```
Position[{4, 5, 2, 1}, _?(#1 >= #2 &)]
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: perhaps [SequencePosition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) ? For example, `SequencePosition[#,{x_,y_}/; x>y]&@{1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 4}`

Comment: @kglr I was *just* about to post that when your comment popped up!  I think I still will.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, please do post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*A couple of these methods were incorrect, one terribly so.  I believe they are now corrected.*

---

Here are some different ideas:

```
f1 = SequencePosition[#, {a_, b_} /; a > b, 1][[1, 1]] &;
f2 = Select[Range@Length@#, x \[Function] #[[x]] > #[[x + 1]], 1][[1]] &;
f3 = Module[{i}, LengthWhile[#, # >= i && (i = #; True) &]] &;
f4 = Position[UnitStep@Differences@#, 0, 1, 1][[1, 1]] &;
f5 = SparseArray[UnitStep@Differences@#, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"][[1]] &;

#[{1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 4}] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}
```

> ```
> {5, 5, 5, 5, 5}
> ```

```
#[{2, 2, 5, 4, 7, 4}] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}
```

> ```
> {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
> ```

And a beautifully terse one from [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov):

```
f6 = Length@First@Split[#, LessEqual] &;
```

#### Benchmarking

A benchmark with the position one third of the way through the list.

Including kglr's functions, and now on a packed array where performance can be highest.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[
  {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, fa, fb, fc, fd}, 
  ReplacePart[Sort@RandomReal[1, #], ⌈#/3⌉ -> 2`] &,
  10,
  ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image]

#### Shootout

It seems that the old warhorse `SparseArray` still rules the noncompiled methods.  Let's compare it to a WVM compiled `f4`:

```
f4C = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Position[UnitStep@Differences@x, 0][[1, 1]]];

BenchmarkPlot[
  {f4, f5, f4C},
  ReplacePart[Sort@RandomReal[1, #], ⌈#/3⌉ -> 2`] &,
  10
]
```

[image]

So it seems `f5` and `f4C` are pretty similar once we get past a constant factor in `f5`.  `f4C` is probably easier for most people to understand, and it might be made faster still with compilation to C.

Comment: `f6 = Length@First@Split[#, Less] &;`

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Are you not going to post that as an answer?

Comment: It is better if you include this in yours.

Comment: @Alexey With credit, I will.

Comment: If you need all the positions where the next list entry is smaller, Alexey's method can be generalized easily as `FoldList[Plus, Length /@ Split[#, Less]] &`.

Comment: @evanb I think all of these methods beside `LengthWhile` would be easily generalized for that case, typically making the code shorter in the process.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For an input of `{1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 4}`, the functions return `{3, 3, 5, 3, 5}`. Something seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @Anjan I am feeling really stupid right now.  I really don't know what i was thinking on some of these, other than *I wasn't.*

Comment: @AnjanKumar would you kindly check to see if my code is working now?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I think we need `LessEqual` in that function and in my latest edit I made this change, but clearly I am not thinking too well today so please check my logic on that as well.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard They all work now :). Thanks for enlightening us with your solutions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are correct, I didn't read the question sufficiently carefully. BTW, we can achieve additional speedup for `f4` by adding `1` as fourth argument to `Position` or replacing it with `FirstPosition`.

Comment: @Anjan That is kind of you.  I have rewritten `f3` to work the way that I had originally envisioned, though I got it terribly wrong the first time.  (1) its current form might interest you (2) if I got it wrong again please let me know!

Comment: @Alexey That seems obvious *after* you say it.  I'll amend the answer yet again. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Also

```
ClearAll[fa, fb, fc, fd]
fa = Position[Partition[#, 2, 1], _?(Greater @@ # &), 1, 1] //. {x_} :> x &;
fb = 1 + LengthWhile[Range@Length@#, Function[{x}, #[[x]] <= #[[x + 1]]]] &;
fc = Block[{i = 1}, While[#[[i]] <= #[[i + 1]], i++]; i] &
fd = FirstPosition[Differences@#,_?Negative][[1]]&

#@{1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 4} & /@ {fa, fb, fc, fd}
```

> {5, 5, 5, 5}

```
#@{1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 4} & /@ {fa, fb, fc, fd}
```

> {3, 3, 3, 3}

**Update:** The functions `fb`, `fc` and `fd` above work in cases where a position that satisfies condition exists in the input list. To handle the general case where the  output may be empty, they can be modified as follows:

```
fb2 = 1 + LengthWhile[Range[Length[#]-1], Function[{x}, #[[x]] <= #[[x + 1]]]] /. 
      Length[#] -> {} &;
fc2 = Block[{i = 1}, While[i < Length@# && #[[i]] <= #[[i + 1]], i++];
     i /. Length[#] -> {}] &;
fd2 = FirstPosition[Differences@#, _?Negative][[1]] /. "NotFound" -> {} &;

#@{1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8} & /@ {fa, fb2, fc2, fd2}
```

> {{}, {}, {}, {}}

Comment: May I add your functions to my benchmark?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, of course  -- i am afraid :)

Comment: I didn't get `fd` into the benchmark but I'm sure I'll find reason to update it again. *edit: Sure enough I realized I was unpacking my reals because I left out a single backtick, so `fd` is now included.*

Comment: I guess I better handle that case too now.  ;-p  But later, I'm tired now.