# How to work with dataset without column names?

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset of 2 columns as follows
    a 1
    b 2 
    c 3

That dataset doesn't have names for both columns, how should I use select to work on it, i.e., get data with the second column number bigger than 2

```
myDataset[Select[#2>2]]  doesn't work,   How to refer the second column?
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes:

- The function must end in `&`
- A whole row of the dataset will be passed to that function *as a list*, so use `#[[2]] > 2&` instead of `#2 > 2&`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

define your data, let's say:

```
myData = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 5}, {e, 45}, {f, 2}, {g, 3}}
```

> {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 5}, {e, 45}, {f, 2}, {g, 3}}

In order to get second column

```
myData[[All, 2]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 5, 45, 2, 3}

So, your query should be something like this:

```
Select[myData[[All, 2]], # > 2 &]
```

> {3, 5, 45, 3}

If you need their position, you can use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-find-the-position-of-elements-in-a-list-satisfying-criteria) (credits to J.M., who also suggests `Flatten` should you need to manipulate somehow your results:

```
Position[myData[[All, 2]], _?(# > 2 &)]
```

> {{3}, {4}, {5}, {7}}